# Shortcut to stop execution of program in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, shortcut, execution

I am using netbeans to code java and i was wondering if there is an option to have a program stopped by pressing a shortcut. I can press <kbd>F6</kbd> to execute program, but I have to use mouse to stop program, which I find a little annoying.

many thanks alfred

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>.

It is defined in `Tools > Options > Keymap` as `System > Cancel Process`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(short/precise). It is correct and will save me a lot of mousing :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Anyway could u help me as well to automate the things? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716395/auto-stop-other-running-project-when-running-1-app-under-netbeans

Comment: How do you do this by mousing?

Answer (score 8):

In Mac: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>