# How do I stop a running process in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

In Netbeans, after running a project (by clicking <kbd>F6</kbd>), how can I stop that running progress as if it were shutdown by the OS (not cancel it)?

On the Output windows of Netbeans, there is only a cancel button, which cancels the running process.

In my program, I handle the shutdown event (`addShutdownHook`), and cancelling the running progress doesn't program jump to shutdown code handler.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new StopThread());
```

Comment: If running from Maven is an option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188534/how-to-stop-a-maven-project-started-in-netbeans

Comment: The same question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375146/shortcut-to-stop-execution-of-program-in-netbeans CTRL + SHIFT + DEL shortcut will end the top running program of the 'stack'.

Answer (score 1):

I only know a simple way: there is a little button below on the right hand, so you can click the photo to see more cleaner. That's all.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgpqc.png)